# R graphics displayed separately of the R GUI in Windows

Tags: r

This question might sound superficial, but if you are a Windows user and install R on it, all graphics are displayed inside the R interface, together with the console window.

My question is whether is possible to customize the GUI in order to work with graphics as a separate window, not included in the R environment, so that we can select it from the Windows panel.

Comment: is maybe `dev.new()` what you're looking for?

Comment: You can right click the graph and then choose one of the copy, save or print options on the menu that appears or you can left click on the graph and choose File from the menu at top and pick the desired option there (in which case you will get more save formats to choose from).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `windows()` function, which has `width` and `height` and [many other arguments](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.4.1/topics/windows)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment. The issue here is that I work with R Commander, and every time I get a graphic, it is open in the GUI, just behind R Commander. And this is unsuspectedly annoying.